# brew update error your CLT does not support macOS 11.2

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew

`brew update` and `brew install` both cause the same error:

```
Error: Your CLT does not support macOS 11.2.
It is either outdated or was modified.
Please update your CLT or delete it if no updates are available.
```

But I have the latest Xcode 12.4 installed, and in Xcode - Preferences - Locations - Command Line Tools is pointed to Xcode 12.4.

Answer (score 5):

First try:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

If still `Error: Your CLT does not support macOS 11.2`, then you need:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

and download and install latest `Command Line Tools` from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: This also works for macOS 13!